# Algorithm for finding the maximum sphere in the gap between a set of spheres

Tags: algorithm, math

I have a set of non-intersecting spheres with known centers and radii, and I want to find the maximum sphere in the gap between these spheres.

Currently my approach is a 'nudge-and-bulge' method in which I pick on a point P in the void near the center of all the spheres, and  I find the largest ball with its center at P. I then let the ball center walk randomly with small steps from P to a new position P' and check if the ball at P' with the old radius intersects with other spheres, if no intersection exists the sphere grows until it hits one sphere, else the center walks again, and repeat.

This approach is quite time-consuming, and I wonder if there is a better way to address the problem. I have searched online and the only relevant discussions are about finding maximum inscribed circle/sphere in between points/polygon/polyhedron.

Comment: When you say maximum sphere, you mean the one with the highest radius right?

Comment: Your problem can be efficiently solved via the construction of the Voronoi diagram of the given set of spheres. It doesn't seem easy to find good references about it, though.

Comment: What do you mean by "between these spheres"? A member of the existing set of spheres? Or a gap which can be filled with a new sphere?

Comment: It may be useful to note that the point where two spheres touch is on the line connecting their centers, and that the length of the line is the sum of the two radii.

Answer (score 0):

If the sphere can't be made bigger by your 'nudge and budge' method, then it must be tangent to at least 4 other spheres.

Given 4 spheres, there is only *one* sphere that is tangent to all of them. (the position and radius are 4 unknowns, determined by the 4 distance equations to the given spheres)

So try all combinations of 4 spheres.  For each combination, find the tangent sphere and see if it intersects any other ones.

That's idea that breaks your problem into a finite number of possibilities.  The simple algorithm takes O(n^5), which is still a long time, though, if you have a lot of spheres.  You can use the 3D Voronoi diagram to greatly accelerate this as @YvesDaoust suggests.